# Product variation attributes does not appear as it should in the cart - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am setting attributes like this:

```
$product_attributes = array();


$product_attributes['Print size'] = array(
    'name' => 'Print size',
    'value' => implode('|', $possiblesizes),
    'position' => 0,
    'is_visible' => 0,
    'is_variation' => 1,
    'is_taxonomy' => 0
);


$product_attributes['Paper type'] = array(
    'name' => 'Paper type',
    'value' => implode('|', $availablematerial),
    'position' => 0,
    'is_visible' => 0,
    'is_variation' => 1,
    'is_taxonomy' => 0
);

update_post_meta($new_post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes);
```

Afterwards I am setting exact variations like this:

```
update_post_meta($variant[$key], 'attribute_print-size', $size);
        update_post_meta($variant[$key], 'attribute_paper-type', $material["name"]);
```

In the product page everything is fine and it comes up as "Print size" and "Paper type", but in the cart these values comes up as:

attribute_print-size

attribute_paper-type

Any idea why this happens?